# Unsure if all content items need a row in the ucm_base table

Tags: tags, com-content

I'm writing a console plug-in in Joomla 4.2.3 to add tags to content items based on field values that'll run on a cron task.

I've generally got it working ok, my code adds a row to the `contentitem_tag_map` table to add a tag to a content item.

My issue is that the `contentitem_tag_map` table has a field called `core_content_id` which seems to relate to the `core_content_id` in the `ucm_content` table and about half of my content items do not have a corresponding row in the `s3ib7_ucm_content`, in which cases I do not have anything to set that field to.

What should I be doing?

Every time I add a tag to an item, should I be adding a row to `ucm_content` and `ucm_base` tables?

Should I be doing this some other way, rather than just trying to add tags via SQL queries?

I have content versioning turned off in com_content and com_tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert records in all relevant tables. There is some code which relies on the `ucm_base` records. Although it's not used by core, it can be used by 3rd party extensions. `ucm_content` table is used more widely, especially in frontend. It's used by Tags component to show list of tagged items, as well as by tag modules.

Generally it's a bad practice to be inserting database records manually. Best use existing APIs. Tagging is now handled by a plugin in `behaviour` group which runs on table events. So you could use the content model or the table class to manage this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sharky that's really useful info and some good pointers.
The bit I don't really understand is why some articles have a ucm_base row and some didn't.  
I've implemented as queries just now, see https://github.com/SSOFB/StreetArtAberdeen/blob/main/public/plugins/system/saaconsole/src/Console/SaaconsoleCommand.php#L291 but I'll look into re-doing it with the APIs.